# How to specify generic-type class information at compile time?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class defined like the following:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {

 private final Class<T> type;

 public GenericClass(Class<T> type) {
      this.type = type;
 }

 public Class<T> getMyType() {
     return this.type;
 }
}
```

With that class code is easy to instantiate a new instance of the class with a non-generic type. For example:

```
GenericClass<String> c = new GenericClass<String>(String.class)
```

My question is the following. How can I create a new instance of the class with a generic type? Example:

```
GenericClass<List<String>> c = new GenericClass<List<String>>(...)
```

If I put `List<String>.class` the compiler gives me an error. At compile time, which syntax should I use to specify to the constructor the right class of the generic type?

Comment: you need to do List.class,

Comment: Due to type erasure, the generic part is lost at runtime anyway. So at runtime, there is no way to distinguish `List` and `List<String>`. Therefore, you should just use `List.class`.

Comment: As others mentioned, it will be hard to capture more information than you could capture by using `List.class`. The information about the type parameter will be lost. However, the Guava `TypeToken` class offers a sophisticated infrastructure for this kind of tasks, and you might definitely want to have a look: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained

Answer (score 2):

A generic doesn't know nor does it care about the generic class being specified, and as such, there's no `List<String>.class`, only `List.class`. Did you consider wildcards? What should `List<?>.class` return? And `List<? extends AnotherClass>.class`? So no, you can't know what specific class a generic is holding at compile time, basically because it can hold different classes that are only fully specified at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that there is only one `List` class object, which you can get from `List.class`. But is it `Class<List>`, `Class<List<Object>>`, `Class<List<String>>`, or `Class<List<?>>`, etc? It can only have one type, and the Java designers chose `Class<List>` (it's the only safe choice). If you really want a `Class<List<String>>`, you'll have to do some unchecked casts:

```
GenericClass<List<String>> c =
    new GenericClass<List<String>>((Class<List<String>>)(Class<?>)List.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to write generics to class type (and therefore make them available at runtime with reflection) is to create sub class of your `GenericClass`. Even anonymous inner class does the job:

```
GenericClass<List<String>> c = new GenericClass<List<String>>(...){};
```

(pay attention on trailing `{}`).

Comment: Note that OP specifies *"at compile-time"*.

Comment: Exactly. At compile time. All anonymous inner classes are created at compile time.

Comment: At compile time means `.class` should work. `GenericClass<List<String>>.class` is still not valid syntax. What you're proposing is making `GenericClass` abstract, sorry I don't see how that solves the problem.

Comment: Obviously I cannot change syntax of java. I just explained how to make generic parameter be written into the byte code.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
    Class<T> type;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericClass() {
        Type type = ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        if (type instanceof Class<?>)
            this.type = (Class<T>)type;
        else if (type instanceof ParameterizedType)
            this.type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)type).getRawType();
        else
            this.type = null;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericClass<Integer> g = new GenericClass<Integer>() {};
    System.out.println(g.getType());

    GenericClass<List<String>> g2 = new GenericClass<List<String>>() {};
    System.out.println(g2.getType());
}
```

Comment: Note the question: *"at compile-time"*.

Comment: I think that the question title mentions compile time, because the error is a compile-time error...  This answer provides a solution for the general problem that's trying to be solved no?

Comment: I think not because question is to get the type at compile-time. You can also freely interpret the question as you did, that's ok, I'm just stating the question proper :D

Comment: "My question is the following. How can I create a new instance of the class with a generic type?" :p

Comment: In title with big, black, bold letters: *"at compile time"* :P